# How to convert a JSON string, to a PHP array, and then back again?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I am writing in PHP. I have this string:

```
    '[["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>","This is example filler text","3:1",4,37],["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>"," Filler text is an example usage of a highlighter JQuery plugin utilized for a drupal module. \n ","5:1",5,85],["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>","Highlights are serialized to when \"save\" button is pressed. \n ","5:3",0,108],["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>","The serialized J","5:5",0,16]]'
```

The above string, is simply a string of a JavaScript style array of arrays. What I would like to be able to do, is convert this to an actual PHP array. But I would also like to be able to convert that PHP array back to this exact string.

The end result would be similar to the end result of doing these steps (I think):

1) remove the first and last single quotation marks

2) replace each '[' character with 'array(' and each ']' character with ')'

Thus I would end up with a valid PHP array of arrays. And I am also unsure of what I would need to do to reverse this process.

Comment: Looks like JSON to me. PHP has built-in functions to pare JSON.

Comment: I agree with @FelixKling.  Have you looked into using `json_decode`?

Comment: @FelixKling Looking into it now! I'm confused at you saying this looks like JSON. Is an array of arrays of strings JSON in PHP? I thought JSON had { "syntax": "like" } <this.

Comment: JSON is just a JavaScript representation of object data, which maps quite nicely to either `stdClass` PHP objects, associative arrays, or indexed arrays in PHP.

Comment: Nope, JSON can also encode lists, which looks like `[v, v, v]`. The string contains JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling (and others) that's interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json_encode` and `json_decode`:

```
$php_array = json_decode('[["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>","This is example filler text","3:1",4,37],["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>"," Filler text is an example usage of a highlighter JQuery plugin utilized for a drupal module. \n ","5:1",5,85],["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>","Highlights are serialized to when \"save\" button is pressed. \n ","5:3",0,108],["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>","The serialized J","5:5",0,16]]', true);
$js_array = json_encode($php_array);
```

Comment: thank's for the reply, Question, will $js_array essentially contain the same exact string value that it had originally?

Comment: Yes and no... the `json_encode` will escape `/`, so `</span>` will become `<\/span>`, as that is proper JSON. But aside from that yes, they will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Javascript

```
    var string = '[["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>","This is example filler text","3:1",4,37],["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>"," Filler text is an example usage of a highlighter JQuery plugin utilized for a drupal module. \n ","5:1",5,85],["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>","Highlights are serialized to when \"save\" button is pressed. \n ","5:3",0,108],["<span class=\"highlighted\" style=\"background-color: yellow;\"></span>","The serialized J","5:5",0,16]]';
$.post("phpfile.php",{data:string},function(data){ var newVar = data.var; },"json");
```

PHP

```
<?php $data = json_decode($_POST["data"]); /*CODE*/ echo json_encode(array("var" => $data)); ?>
```